running postgres DB in docker but its not connecting to my username and password env variables?
I'm am unable to figure this out, i'm trying to connect to the postgres instance running on docker. within the environment variables i selected
postgres:
    image: postgres:latest
    container_name: postgres
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
      POSTGRES_DB: voting
    healthcheck:
      test: [ "CMD", "pg_isready", "-U", "postgres" ]
      interval: 10s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 5

My understanding of this. is where i select the superuser that postgres runs on, which should be postgres for both username and password.
Now when i do try and connect using sqlalchemy
engine = create_tables_for_voting.create_tables("postgresql+psycopg2://postgres:postgres@localhost:5432/voting")

Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
session = Session()

This should ideally work but the error messages i'm getting on the terminal side is
There was an error when connection to db: (psycopg2.OperationalError) connection to server at "localhost" (::1), port 5432 failed: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "username"
Now when i do query through docker there is no user called username
enter image description here
Really stumped here and i think its something simple i must be overlooking
I've tried changing the user and have also tried checking the different users available and nothing worked
No other users implemented

Your sessionmaker is getting an engine from elsewhere.

FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "username"

Engine being used has "username" defined as username, and this is being used to authenticate.

Now when i do query through docker there is no user called username

Exactly, your PG instance doesn't have a user "username", but it's not the problem. PG instance is alright!
So...

"postgresql+psycopg2://postgres:postgres@localhost:5432/voting"

Is being ignored or overwritten somewhere. Take a good look into your code base.

You were right i forgot to remove a previous definition that i had done, although now the error i'm getting is completely different, there is an error when connecting to localhost. From what i've read instead of localhost you put your docker definition  of the service instead but when i have done that it still doesn't connect

@Theonewhodoesn'tknow1012 localhost should work, but you need to open a new question with details
